# How can I easily see my own questions and threads to which I have commented on this site?

Tags: discussion

How can I easily see my own questions and threads to which I have commented on this site?

I cannot find something relevant on the top right near the user's badges links.

Answer (score 6):

Simply click on the area containing your icon and that will take you to your user profile.

From there, scroll down to your list of *Newest questions* or select the appropriate tab for other options.

> [image: Newest questions]

To see things like comments, select the *Activity* tab and then *Responses* from the left panel which will show responses from others to you. Otherwise, if you want to see only your responses then select *All actions* → *Comments*

> [image: Responses]

Comment: thanks, beat me to it... though I notice 'my comments' is not a function there, unless my blindness continues.

Comment: @pierrely, You need a wide window to see the left panel (quick fix: fullscreen). In 'All actions' you will find your comments alongside your other actions.

Comment: thanks I was on wide full screen with eyes wide shut, got it.